# How to change blue color on android ListView?

Tags: android, android-listview, colors

[image]

How change this blue color to other in android listview.

thks

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can set it cache color

```
 setCacheColorHint(Color.RED);
```

Comment: not worked to me. thks

Comment: @GrlsHu: Your answer "setCacheColorHint();" is for, when you want to use fading edges.  The question asked is for overScroll color changing effect.  Hope it clears.

Answer (score 0):

use following attributes in your ListView to change the colour of overscroll

```
android:overScrollHeader="@drawable/your_drawable_file"
android:overScrollFooter="@drawable/your_drawable_file"
```

or

```
android:overScrollHeader="#fff"
android:overScrollFooter="#fff"
```

you can use your own drawable instead of "@drawable/your_drawable_file"

if you want to avoid overscroll permenently use following method

```
<ListView android:overScrollMode="never" />
```

or

```
<ListView 
android:overscrollHeader="@null" 
android:overscrollFooter="@null" />
```

or refer the following two methods at android API,

[setOverScrollHeader](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setOverscrollHeader%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)
[setOverSCrollFooter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ListView.html#setOverscrollFooter%28android.graphics.drawable.Drawable%29)

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot how it works?

Comment: dude im busy right now... Check it yourself, this may be not working in ICS, remember that also...

Comment: this worked: <ListView android:overScrollMode="never" /> but the others solution not. I'm set <ListView 
android:overscrollHeader="@android:color/holo_green_dark" 
android:overscrollFooter="@android:color/holo_green_dark" /> but not worked.

Comment: these setters are used to add drawables that show when the
list overshoots. They are not meant to replace the glow effect. You
probably don't see your drawables becasue by default the list
overshoots by only a few pixels.



https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-developers/ZLD5Blw4svw